# Bootstrap4 nav menu not expanding

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded" id="menutop">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-content" aria-controls="nav-content" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <!-- Brand -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            BRAND
        </a>


        <!-- Links -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="nav-content">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">COMO FUNCIONA</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">TRABAJA CON NOSOTROS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">TIENDA</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">BLOG</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">EQUIPO</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">REPARA</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

When collapsing the menu on pressing the icon it does not drop down.

I have copied and pasted the example on Bootstrap's tutorial page
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown link
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The nav toggle icon is showing at my left and its not expanding even with large screens. Also it is not showing the menu.
[image]

Why may this happen? Bugs? I am using Angular CLI and the latest version for Bootstrap. I'm using CDN.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the `navbar-light` to `navbar-dark`? Sometimes the BG & link color are both white and thus, you can't see them.

Comment: somehow navbar-dark doesnt exist on my css..  so weird

Comment: Which bootstrap CSS are you using? CDN? And are you using the Alpha release or the new one, the Beta?

Comment: I'm using  <CDN 4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

it seems that js is not working on your page yet, please check if js file is actually called

Comment: how do I check that?

Comment: more or less like this, adjust where the location of your js file, if the local computer you point to it @Alex

<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

I am added below CDN files now it's working properly.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script> <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```html
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded" id="menutop">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-content" aria-controls="nav-content" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <!-- Brand -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            BRAND
        </a>


        <!-- Links -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="nav-content">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">COMO FUNCIONA</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">TRABAJA CON NOSOTROS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">TIENDA</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">BLOG</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">EQUIPO</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">REPARA</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
 
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown link
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```